# Какие есть способы перемешать элементы массива в java?

Tags: java, массивы, случайные-числа

Какие есть способы перемешать элементы массива в java?

кроме:

```
int[] arr = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70};

Random rnd = new Random();
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    int index = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
    int a = arr[index];
    arr[index] = arr[i];
    arr[i] = a;
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-

Answer (score 4):

Вы можете использовать готовый метод [`shuffle()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-).

```
List<Integer> res = Arrays.asList(Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new));   
Collections.shuffle(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть еще такой вариант:

```
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();
        int[] arr = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70};
        int[] newArray = new int[arr.length];
        List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<>(arr.length);
        int count = 0;
        while (true) {
            int var = random.nextInt(arr.length);
            if (!indexes.contains(var)) {
                indexes.add(var);
                newArray[var] = arr[count++];
            }
            if (count == arr.length) {
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArray));
    }

}
```